# Can't connect to my own hosted mongoDB server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have my own home server, where i have nginx configured and some api's and webs there. also set up a mongoDb server there, the thing is I can't connect from vercel or heroku to it, but when I try to connect from different internet connections like in a coffee shop I can connect and work.

this is the error I get

[image]

someone can give me a little help? also I don't know why in map is showing my local IP in the URL that I use already configured my public ip.

[image]

Comment: Is that a replica set? i.e. does `rs.conf()` from a mongo shell return anything?

Comment: yes i also tried using ?replicaSet=res0 but also not working.

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63601964/2282634