# Can't connect to MongoDB single-node replica set via Mongo Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to set up a Mongo replica set in my local environment via Docker Compose such that I can test Transactions locally. I followed this setup [here](https://medium.com/workleap/the-only-local-mongodb-replica-set-with-docker-compose-guide-youll-ever-need-2f0b74dd8384#:%7E:text=Single%2Dnode%20replica%20set%20setup), and it seems to spin up fine - my API can connect and communicate with it as expected.

My configuration looks like this:

[image: docker-compose configuration]

However, I can no longer connect to the instance via Mongo Atlas, which I use to view what collections are within my DB instance.

Any insight into this?

When I spin up my Docker containers, my Node API and Mongo (based on the linked configuration) spin up fine, and communicate with each other as expected.

However, when I try to connect to the Mongo instance via Atlas, I receive a "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.docker.internal" error.

[image: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.docker.internal error]

I'm only trying to get this Replica Set working as it's required to use Transaction logic. We have remote Mongo instances with Replica sets which I assume will work fine - however, I'd like to test this Transaction logic before pushing to Production.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/63601964/2282634

Comment: @Joe this seems to be a different scenario. I'm trying to run my replica set on my local machine and connect to it via Mongo Compass.

Comment: That is the same underlying issue.  The hostname being returned from the seed connection appears to be "host.docker.internal", which is not being resolved.   You will either need to make it so that hostname resolves, or use replicaSetHorizons to return different host names.